# How to update max date of a record table based on join with another table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables.

Job: jobid, jobname, jobdate

JobLog: jobid, jobtask, actiondate

I want to run a query to update the Job.jobdate with the latest value from Joblog.

Example:

```
SELECT JOBID, MAX(ACTIONDATE)
FROM JOBLOG
GROUP BY JOBID
```

Above query gives me max date per Job ID.

```
UPDATE J
SET J.JOBDATE=MAX(JL.ACTIONDATE)
FROM JOB J
JOIN JOBLOG JL ON J.JOBID=JL.JOBID
```

My confusion is that the above query will update all JobDates with the max date. How to ensure max is updated based on join?

Is the solution to write like following?

```
UPDATE J
SET J.JOBDATE=JL.ACTIONDATE
FROM JOB J
JOIN (SELECT JOBID, MAX(ACTIONDATE) AS ACTIONDATE
      FROM JOBLOG
      GROUP BY JOBID) JLGroupBy
ON J.JOBID=JLGroupBy.JOBID
```

Or the following:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT JOBID, MAX(ACTIONDATE) AS ACTIONDATE
          FROM JOBLOG
          GROUP BY JOBID)
UPDATE J
SET J.JOBDATE=JL.ACTIONDATE
FROM JOB 
JOIN CTE ON CTE.JOBID=JOB.JOBID
```

Or is there any better/cleaner approach?

Comment: Your first solution is the simplest, but the second is preferred by some. They are both exactly the same, just a matter of readability. The updatable CTE in the answer below performs differently, I'd be surprised if it was better

Comment: I'm curious to know how does the CTE know which table/column it needs to update - is it that smart :) ?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server supports updatable CTEs and views. The column must be directly fed through, it cannot be computed, and the table to be updated cannot be a union or grouped or distinct

Answer (score 1):

I would express this using an updatable CTE with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT J.*, MAX(JL.ACTIONDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY J.JOBID) MAXACTIONDATE
    FROM JOB J
    INNER JOIN JOBLOG JL ON JL.JOBID = J.JOBID
)

UPDATE cte
SET JOBDATE = MAXACTIONDATE;
```

Comment: Is your SQL query better than my query (see my last query please).

Comment: Your second query is fine.  You may compare the performance between our answers, but I'll bet you will the performance to be similar.

Comment: I have added another SQL query using CTE at the bottom, maybe that is similar as well. I find that your CTE query is confusing as I don't know how the cte is able to update underlying query

Comment: If you are going to mention performance, then your query should also include a filter to avoid updating the rows that are already set to MAXACTIONDATE. It is generally NEVER a good idea to set a column to the value it already contains.